# Simple String and variable problem using jQuery

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

I'm trying to add my var to this string:

```
var liPad = 20;

$(this).css({'width' : width , 'height' : height, 'padding' : "'0px' + liPad + 'px'"});
```

To make it work like this:

```
$(this).css({'width' : width , 'height' : height, 'padding' : '0 20px'});
```

Can't figure out how to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(this).css({
    'width': width,
    'height': height,
    'padding': '0 ' + liPad + 'px'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you needed a space where the yyyyyyy is. it was 0px20px

padding' : "'0pxyyyyyyy' + liPad + 'px'"});

The following should work:

```
var liPad = 20;
$(this).css({'width' : width , 'height' : height, 'padding' : "'0px ' + liPad + 'px'"});
```